# java list<map> with repeated values

Tags: java, list, dictionary, hashmap

I have a `List<Map>` which should be of the below syntax:

```
[{clientName=abcd}, {clientName=defg}]
```

Previously I had `List<Bean>` which I want to replace with `List<Map>`.

Here is my code:

```
List<Map> clientList=new ArrayList<Map>();
Map<String,String> clientNameMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

    clientNameMap.put("clientName","abcd");
    clientList.add(clientNameMap);

    clientNameMap.put("clientName","defg");
    clientList.add(clientNameMap);
```

What happens with this code is, I am getting `[{clientName=defg}, {clientName=defg}]` as the output where, `clientName=abcd` is replaced by the 2nd value `defg`. How can I get the expected result which is  `[{clientName=abcd}, {clientName=defg}]`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to re-initialize your `Map<>` again before adding to `List<>` because you are changing previous reference for `Map<>` object and on same key that will change previous object also.

You code should be :

```
List<Map> clientList=new ArrayList<Map>();
Map<String,String> clientNameMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

clientNameMap.put("clientName","abcd");
clientList.add(clientNameMap);

clientNameMap = new HashMap<String,String>();  //Initialize it again.
clientNameMap.put("clientName","defg");
clientList.add(clientNameMap);
```

Comment: Thanks.. :) I will be adding it in a for loop.

Comment: re-initializing your Map<> creates new map object so i think instead of re initializing adding different keys for same map as clientName-1,clientName-2 will be good..

Comment: @mady your are right, but user requirement is adding it on same key. She also mention that `Previously I had List<Bean> which I want to replace with List<Map>` It means that key name will same for different object.

Answer (score 1):

First read up on Map and List. When you add a Map object (or any other object) to a List object, all you're doing is adding a reference to that object in the List.

It means that if you change the Map contents after adding it to the List object, that will be reflected in the List.

In a Map, moreover, the key has to be unique.

So here you need to create a new Map object before you can add the new value and add that new Map object to the list.

See this other post for details:[copying a java hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079266/copying-a-java-hashmap)

Comment: Ok..so creating the map within a for loop and adding values to it, does the job for me.. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, Map key should be unique so when you put value to same key n times the value is just replaced for the key, In your code you are replacing the value for same key(clientName) and adding it to list so it is printing the same value which you put in last to map.

```
List<Map> clientList=new ArrayList<Map>();
Map<String,String> clientNameMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

clientNameMap.put("clientName-1","abcd");
clientList.add(clientNameMap);

clientNameMap.put("clientName-2","defg");
clientList.add(clientNameMap);
```