# copy map to another new map

Tags: java, pointers, hashmap

I have 2 HashMap as follow:

```
@Session
private Map< Integer, List< ObjectA >> keyMap;

@Session
private Map< Integer, List< ObjectA >> keyMap2;
```

At first, I will put some data inside `keyMap`, and then I try to store the data inside `keyMap` to `keyMap2`:

```
keyMap2 = keyMap;
```

And then, I will edit some data inside `keyMap`. However, the value inside `keyMap2` will changes as what I have edit in `keyMap`.

As I understanding, it is because `keyMap2` is only point to `keyMap` pointer, so anything change in `keyMap`, it will reflect in `keyMap2`, because same pointer. (Please correct me if I am wrong.)

I wish to keep the `keyMap2` value without changes like `keyMap`. Any idea other than I loop `keyMap` and put 1 by 1 inside `keyMap2`.

Comment: `keyMap2 = new HashMap<>(keyMap)`.

Comment: hi @saka1029, this does not work for me. I think is maybe of my HashMap contain a list inside. I and make changes for the list for `keyMap`

Answer (score 3):

```
keyMap2 = new HashMap<Integer, List<ObjectA>>(keyMap);
```

Swap out HashMap for whatever Map implementation you prefer or require.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy using Java 8 Stream like this.

```
    Map<String, List<ObjectA>> keyMap2 = keyMap.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), new ArrayList<>(e.getValue())))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

This code copies the lists of the values of `keyMap`.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: As mentioned in the comment the original approach won't work due to copying the contained List by reference.

If the approach using Java8 streams does not work another possibility would be iterating over the Map with:

```
for (keyMap.Entry<Integer, List<ObjectA>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    //Code
}
```

You can then copy the contents into keyMap2 using `entry.getKey()` and a shallow or deep copy of the List from `entry.getValue()`

If a shallow copy (copy ObjectA by reference) is all that's required `new ArrayList<ObjectA>(entry.getValue())`should work, but for a deep copy (need new instances of ObjectA) further information about the object is needed.

---

Original:

You need to copy the hashmap in its entirety.

This is covered in: [copying a java hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079266/copying-a-java-hashmap)

In essence `private Map< Integer, List< ObjectA >> keyMap2 = new HashMap< Integer, List< ObjectA >>(keyMap);`

Or alternatively `keyMap2.addAll(keyMap);`

Comment: The map interface offers indeed the method putAll, doesn't it?

Comment: Hi, this does not work for me. `keyMap2.clear( );` `keyMap2.putAll( serviceAccountsKeyMap );` The `keyMap2` value still change if I change the value inside `keyMap`

Comment: Wait, are you changing the content of keyMap or the properties of some object which is contained by that map? In the latter case, you are still suffering the aliasing problem...

Answer (score 0):

The problem you ran across is called *aliasing*.

In order to break it for your case, you have to:

- define the `clone` method on your class `ObjectA`
- iterate over the `keySet` of the first map, thus:

  - get the `List` instance associated to the specific key
  - create a new instance of that list
  - iterate over former, clone the contained elements and put them in the latter
  - put the new list in the second map, along with the key used to get the original list

This way, you are creating from scratch a new list and a full set of elements that are equals to the original ones in terms of content, but are not the same objects in memory.

Comment: Hi, this does not work for me. 

`keyMap2.clear( );`
 `keyMap2.putAll( serviceAccountsKeyMap );`

The `keyMap2` value still change if I change the value inside `keyMap`

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly mentioned, `keyMap2` is pointing to same HashMap as `keyMap`

But if you do :

```
keyMap2 = (HashMap<String, String>) keyMap.clone();
```

This will make copy of `keyMap` and point `keyMap2` to that copy. Any changes to `keyMap` further will not reflect in the copy

This will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

In Java there are no such things as pointers. Use (use C\C++ for that) so your changes will not reflect. You can use:

```
keyMap2 = (HashMap<String, String>) keyMap.clone();
```

Or:

```
keyMap.putAll(keyMap2) //This will add all the keys in "keymap" to "keymap2"
//Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html
```

Again, the changes will not reflect because there are no `pointers` in Java.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 Stream and method reference:

```
 Map<Integer, List<ObjectA>> keyMap2 = keyMap.entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Or if you wanted to copy the List within the keyMap as well to another list then

```
Map<Integer, List<ObjectA>> keyMap2 = keyMap.entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> new ArrayList<ObjectA>(e.getValue())));
```