# Assigning a map to a new map in java, and then changing the new map also changes original map

Tags: java, collections

I have a use case which looks something like this :

```
    Map<String,String> pr = new HashMap<>();
    pr.put("ab","ab");
    pr.put("xy","xy");
    Map<String,String> prNew = new HashMap<>();
    prNew = pr;
    prNew.remove("ab");
    System.out.println(pr);
    System.out.println(prNew);
```

This is the output i got :

```
{xy=xy}
{xy=xy}
```

But I was expecting 'pr' to remain as :

```
{ab=ab, xy=xy}
```

It looks like prNew took a reference of pr, and any modifications to prNew will modify pr as well.

So how do i get around this? In my use case I need to take a copy of pr and make some changes but it should not affect the original pr.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You want to copy your map, not just assign it. HashMap already has a copy constructor that you can use: `prNew = new HashMap<>(pr);`

Comment: It's not "it looks like" ==> it is !

Comment: Read this for reference: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value). Also: [Copying a HashMap in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079266/copying-a-hashmap-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why the code doesn't work

You create the following in memory:

[image]

So when you change 1 map, you change both, because they are the same map.

## Solution

You need to make a copy of the map if you want to change 1 while keeping the other the same.

You can do this using the constructor which takes a map in.

Answer (score 1):

- for the moment `pr` and `prNew` reference the **same** object, a modification on `pr` or `prNew` is the same, they are just aliases for the same Map
- when you create `prNew` you have to use [the constructor that takes another Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap-java.util.Map-), to make a copy of, all the mappings will be copied into the new one

```
//...

Map<String, String> prNew = new HashMap<>(pr); // <--
prNew.remove("ab");
System.out.println(pr);     // {ab=ab, xy=xy}
System.out.println(prNew);  // {xy=xy}
```