# Create mutable collections (Map.of and List.of)

Tags: java

Looks like `Map.of()` and `List.of()` both create immutable collections. That's useful, but I am looking for a way to create mutable collections sometimes using a factory method.

When I try: `HashMap.of()` I get this error:

> Static method may be invoked on containing interface class only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying a HashMap in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079266/copying-a-hashmap-in-java)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`HashMap` has a constructor that can take another `Map`, so you can create a `HashMap` by passing it whatever `Map.of(...)` produces:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(Map.of("k1", "v1", "k2", "v2"));
```

Likewise for `ArrayList` and `List.of(...)`.

Comment: so that might be `new ArrayList<>(List.of())` right

Comment: @AlexanderMills Yes, exactly.

Comment: I am really starting to hate Java slowly.. why every other language can evolve to be expressive while Java has to stay like this? This is th emain reason I will move to Kotlin as soon as possible (and I am not picking Scala just because of impossibility at work)

Comment: @nrtp: Java is evolving, the uptake is just very slow unfortunately. `List.of()` and `Map.of()` are unfortunately considered *relatively* recent additions, even though Java 9 was released 4 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using Javas' "double brace initialization".  This allows for the nice, short, one-line initialization syntax without creating unnecessary intermediate object instances.

```
HashMap<String, String> mutableMap = new HashMap<>(1) {{ put("key", "value"); }};
```

Comment: Be aware that this creates a new anonymous inner class (with a static initializer). Could be fine, could be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I use a custom method inside of the utils class. Please try, it works correctly.

```
public static Map<String, Object> mutableMap(Object... args) {
        return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < args.length, i -> i + 2)
                        .filter(i -> i + 1 < args.length)
                        .boxed()
                        .collect(toMap(i -> (String) args[i], i -> args[i + 1], (a, b) -> b, HashMap::new));
}
```

Also, you can add validation on paired number of arguments OR add logic to replace the 'null' value according to your requires.